# C++ - default initialisation of a reference member - how does this even work?

Tags: c++, reference

Default initialization of a reference variable generates an error in GCC 4.8, but the following seems to compile and work without any warning/error.

```
struct Foo {
    int &bar;

    Foo(): bar(bar) { }
};

int main () {
  Foo foo;
  cout << foo.bar;  // prints 0
  return 0;
}
```

How does this compile? I'm particularly perplexed by this line:

```
Foo(): bar(bar) { }
```

Comment: Thats pretty good/weird.  How did you even find that??

Comment: What would cause you to try such a thing?  Was it accidental?

Comment: I stumbled on it quite accidentally!

Comment: You have just initialised `bar` with an uninitialised value. So you probably have compiler warning about that.

Comment: In Microsoft VS2013, it compiles okay (no warnings, no errors), but causes a run-time error when trying to access `foo.bar`.

Comment: [CWG issue 453](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#453).

Comment: @T.C.: I think you wanted this one: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#504

Comment: @Deduplicator Both are related, really. Technically the current spec ("A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.") would require a diagnostic, even though it would be impossible in many cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work, it's undefined behaviour.

It compiles because you can, in general, refer to a variable in its initialiser. This can have valid uses:

```
void * p = &p;
```

but in most cases leads to UB. You should get a warning about using an uninitialised value, if you enable sufficent warnings. In GCC, `-Wuninitialized` (or `-Wall`) should do it.

Comment: Anyway, naming the argument the same as the corresponding member can make sense: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af6c4e5e437e6285

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the `void *p = &p` example? I don't quite follow what's happening here.

Comment: @jeffreyveon: It's declaring a pointer, and initialising it with its own address. That's an example of when using the name (but not the value) of a variable in its initialiser is well-defined.